# read/write two xml files at once with XStream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

How is it possible to serialize two xml files at once in one class using XStream?

I have an xml which should get splited in two files and stored on different directories. I want to load them in the same class.
Afterwards, changes should be saved in only one of these two xml files.